# Empty file called 'sudo' in home directory

Tags: sudo, opensuse

I have encountered empty file just called 'sudo' in home directory. The file size is 0 bytes. Is it safe to just delete this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's not a system file. It was probably created by mistake. Check its owner and creation date, that'll tell you more about it.

You can safely delete it.  At worst, you can recreate it via the command `touch ~/sudo`.

Config files and other system files usually start with a dot (`.`). These are the so-called dotfiles, and you should not touch them unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

It would be weird if this file served any regular purpose. You can add to your question the output of your shell history filtered for `sudo` if it's not too long, and it should be clear where the file came from. The command to get that is

```
history | grep sudo
```

There's a good chance the file was created not from your shell though. If the ownership is `root` you can run the same command from root.